# Calculating Cell Averages of Multiple .csv Files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have many csv files and I need to calculate the average value of a particular each particular cell. A simplified example of these csv files are below. In my actual files there is more than one value field but for simplicity's sake I only put one for the example.

File0.csv:

`Latitude, Longitude, Value
23, 97, 1
24, 97, 5
25, 97, 6
26, 97, 4`

File1.csv:

`Latitude, Longitude, Value
23, 97, 7
24, 97, 4
25, 97, 2
26, 97, 9`

Each of the files has the same lat/lons and the same number of rows/columns, I just need to create a new csv that contains the average values at each lat/lon.

An example of the desired output csv:

`Latitude, Longitude, Value
23, 97, 4
24, 97, 4.5
25, 97, 4
26, 97, 6.5`

Another note: I do have some NoData values within my csv files (given a value of -999.9) which may create some averaging issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experienced with the libraries PySpark or Pandas, you could use their `read_csv` and `groupby` methods. Otherwise, another option is to use `open()` to open the file and read it with Python IO, and manually add to a 2 dimensional list while keeping track of the number of elements within each list. For example,

```
values = []
for line in file:
    values.append([line.split(','), 1])

counter = 0

for file2 in files:
    for line in file2:
        if counter > values.length:
            values.append([line.split(','), values[counter][1] + 1])
        else:
            values[counter] = [map(lambda x, y: x + y, values[counter][0], line.split(',')), values[counter][1] + 1]

values[i] = [[j / values[i][1] for j in values[i][0]] for i in range(len(values))]
```

The overall premise is fairly simple; the code is just somewhat messy. If you are are going to be manipulating data in this way very often, I suggest you use PySpark or Pandas. Something that may take 20 lines of code in pure Python would require only 2-3 lines of code in those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To read CSV file:

```
def read_CSV_to_matrix(filename):
    matrix = []
    with open(str(filename)) as f:
        for line in f:
            matrix.append(int(line.strip().split(",")))
    return matrix
```

Then you iterate through both your matrices:

```
for index, line in matrix1:
    # for each line in F0.csv, print element 1, 2 and the average
    # of element 3 in the both matrices
    print(line[0], line[1], (line[2]+matrix2[index][2])/2)
```

Disclaimer: I'm a noob (only 2 years of xp with Python 3)

Comment: Generally speaking, splitting purely on `,` is not advisable.  Take the example: `"a","b,c", "d"` which only has 3 data elements but would give 4 items if you split on comma alone.
Python has many csv parsing modules such as `csv`